# Cannot run shell script from java Command Line

Tags: java, bash, shell

I'm trying to run this script shell from java, but it's not working.

I get this error message:

```
Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
```

Can someone help?

```
String pwd = "blabla";

String s_key = "0000";

String path = "C:/Files/scripts"; 

CommandLine commandLine = CommandLine.parse("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Git\\bin\\git.exe");

commandLine.addArgument("fileName.sh");

commandLine.addArgument(password);

commandLine.addArgument(s_key);

DefaultExecutor defaultExecutor = new DefaultExecutor();

ByteArrayOutputStream sdtout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

ByteArrayOutputStream sdterr = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

PumpStreamHandler streamHandler = new PumpStreamHandler(sdtout, sdterr);

defaultExecutor.setStreamHandler(streamHandler);

defaultExecutor.execute(commandLine);
```

Here is the script

```
#!/bin/sh

pwd=$1
s_key=$2
....
echo $pwd
```

it works well with git bash

```
  $ ./fileName.sh blabla 0000
  nkfjWmiG7dDnYUmjr6VD0A==
```

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the Exception or the stderr/stdout of the executor? https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/exec/ExecuteStreamHandler.html

Comment: you said "works well with git bash", in order to execute the shell you need to open the Git Bash console ? o you can execute the shell directly on the Windows cmd console ?

Comment: @reos yes i use git bash console, i've updated the question with console output. The script doesn't work on windows cmd console... thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are some points to be aware of.

1. If you want to run the git bash command you need to execute the git-bash.exe, on the cmd console you need to execute this command:

> ```
> %windir%\system32\cmd.exe /c ""C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe" --login -i -- D:\temp\test.sh param1"
> ```

2. If you want to execute it from a java app it's the same, the command you need to execute is git-bash.exe not git.exe. 
   This is an example of running a command from java. I'm not using the objects that you're using but the simple java objects. However you can adapt it to your code.

> ```
>  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
>           String[] command = {"C:\\\\Program Files\\\\Git\\\\git-bash.exe",
>                   "D:\\temp\\test.sh",
>                   "param1"};
>           ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
>           processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
>           processBuilder.start();
>       }
> ```

Comment: the --login -i part might be important. So you should add it to your command.
String[] command = {"C:\\\\Program Files\\\\Git\\\\git-bash.exe",
"--login",
"-i",
"D:\\temp\\test.sh",
"param1"};

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple issues with your code:

- You don't seem to be inspecting the stderr/stdout of the program, or inspecting the Exception that gets thrown.
- Git.exe doesn't take shell scripts as the first argument.  As @reos says, you probably need to invoke `git-bash.exe` rather than `git.exe`

Comment: thanks for your reply; i've updated the code with the stderr/stdout. now the error message is `Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)`. where should i put the file "fileName.sh" in the code?

Comment: Updated per reos' answer.  Try invoking `git-bash.exe` rather than `git.exe`